# How to solve the trajectory equation using quadratic drag formula?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, projectile, drag

I am doing a project on ballistics and projectiles and I was reading [this link here](https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/systems/Lab_Notes/traj.pdf) and it states that the ballistics equation cannot be integrated analytically, and has to be integrated numerically. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I see you're a pupil, not a university student. When you go to university, you'll learn about special kind of equations called differential equations. Those equations can be solved by what's called integration. Some times it is impossible to integrate them, then people use numerical methods (i.e. numerical integration). You'll learn about it in university as well. There is a lot to explain here. I suggest you talk to your teacher. To do your project, don't use derivatives as shown in the link you gave (derivatives are those dots above the letters). Substitute them with divisions over time.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh I think your advice shouldn't be generalized. Schools and contexts may vary wildly. I did learn to use some basic differential equations while at school. for example in L-C-circuits (we're talking about Germany in my case). Derivates might be fine as well.

Comment: Why on Earth are people voting to close this as "homework-like"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say a differential equation can be solved we normally mean the solution can be written as a [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), which is summarised as:

> In mathematics, a closed-form expression is a mathematical expression that uses a finite number of standard operations. It may contain constants, variables, certain well-known operations (e.g., + − × ÷), and functions (e.g., nth root, exponent, logarithm, trigonometric functions, and inverse hyperbolic functions), but usually no limit, differentiation, or integration. The set of operations and functions may vary with author and context.

But this is the exception rather than the rule. The vast majority of differential equations have solutions that cannot be written as a closed form expression. This doesn't mean they can't be solved, only that that the solutions are more complicated than the small number of functions that the closed form allows. For example many differential equations will have solutions that are [gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) or [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) or one of the many other functions that are not generally considered to belong to a *closed form* solution.

This is a somewhat artificial distinction. After all why should we say that the *sine* function is closed form while the *gamma* function is not? At the end of the day it comes down to convention. For example our (scientific) calculators all have a button for *sine* but not a button for *gamma*, so we tend to included *sine* in closed form expressions but exclude *gamma*.

We could define a new function *foo* as the solution to the ballistics equation, then claim the ballistics equation has a closed form solution because the solution is *foo*. However this isn't very helpful as none of the computers I use have a *foo* function. That's why we just say the ballistics equation has no closed form solution.

Note that the ballistics equation does have a closed form solution for the special case [where the trajectory is vertical](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/quadrag.html). It's only the general case that has no closed form solution.